# Is the restriction to $H$ applied on both $G, N$ or only on $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading Ash's Basic Abstract Algebra. Here:

> [image]

I got a - perhaps - useless question: When we restrict $G\to G/N$ to $H$, do we consider this restriction on both $G,N$ or only on $G$? Perhaps it doesn't matter but I've been thinking and it looks that both alternatives are fine.

Answer (score 2):

The term "restriction" here refers to the map $\pi$. 
Generally, let $f:G\to G'$ be a map then the restriction of $f$ to $H\subset G$ is the map $f_0:H \to f(H)$, i.e. you restrict the domain of $f$ (which is $G$) to $H$.

Comment: But then, we get the map $H\to H/N$, right? This is confusing to me because it could be $H\to H/H\cap N$. I don't know if it would make a difference.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is the first case. Otherwise it would be tautologicaly trivial.

Comment: Essentially you want to ask about the image of $\pi_0$. Well, the solution you quoted actually answered that question for you, and it's neither of the two cases you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

When a function $\pi \colon G \to G/N$ is restricted to $H \subset G$, it means that we form the function $\pi|_{H} \colon H \to G/N$ defined by $\pi|_{H} (h) = pi(h)$. The restriction only takes place on $G$. As far as I can see we never restrict $N$ when we restrict the function $\pi$.